# How does the item drop system work?

Tags: killing-floor-2

What are the info on item drop frequency, caps, timers and reset times? How does the item drop system work?

Also, when exactly will I get item drops? Are match length, type, difficulty or victory/defeat status, factors on when I get an item drop?

Comment: Also wondering about this, from my experience I believe I have only gotten drops after victories so far, but I haven<t played that much, so it might be coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering this for a while myself having just gotten the game. I played for a few hours yesterday and only received 1 cosmetic after a (basic training) solo game, and 1 crate after a multiplayer game during my entire play time.

After checking out a few places online it seems to be on **a timer of every 24 hours**, with no bearing on difficulty, length, victory/defeat etc. And the timer is for both solo and multiplayer each.

[Source:](https://www.reddit.com/r/killingfloor/comments/3vcdwo/how_the_drop_system_works/)

> Myself and the community of KF2 on Steam forums have tried multiple
>   ways of figuring the drop system. Here's what we came up with;
>
> - You do NOT need to kill the final boss (win game)
> - Any difficulty and any length works
> - You only get the drop when the game ends (everyone dies or win game)
> - For some reason playing solo (get few kills then let zombie kill you) will increase your drop rate I've had 5-6 hours of online
>     gameplay and got no drops, I tried solo play once for 5 minutes, got
>     10 kills then killed myself and got my first drop, I'm not the only
>     one who tried this method and worked.

There doesn't seem to be any sort of indication from other players or developers on frequency of drop types, but the tendency sounds to be crates and cosmetics with keys being rare (since they likely want you to spend money to buy keys).

Other sources and their information:

> [1:](http://twinfinite.net/2016/11/killing-floor-2-how-to-get-crate-drops/) Since you can only earn one reward every 24 hours, you can breeze
>   through a couple short matches if you aren’t looking to invest a ton
>   of time into playing. They usually drop after the first or second
>   match, usually with a 30-minute time frame from when you start.
>   Through our playing we have not been able to acquire more than one
>   reward a day, however this could get changed in time.

---

> [2:](https://www.reddit.com/r/killingfloor/comments/5dzd6h/how_do_drops_work_ps4/) Its one Drop per Day (or all 24 Hours) You can get Weapons
>   Skins, Cosmetics or Usb/Crates